# Limit as x goes to infinity of this problem?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Find the limit as $x$ goes to $\infty$ of $\cfrac{\sqrt{x^2 + 16} + x}{x+3}$

I multiplied by the conjugate, but now I'm stuck. Now the denominator has a radical.

Answer (score 5):

In this case you just need to note that the highest power of $x$ occurring in numerator or denominator is $x^1$.  Dividing top and bottom by this,
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+16}+x}{x+3}=\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{16}{x^2}}+1}{1+\frac3x}$$
and you should now be able to find the limit as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: is it because the sqrt of x^2 is actually x?

Comment: Yes.  The highest power is "really" $x^1$ because the $x^2$ is under a square root sign.

Comment: Depends, if the OP means both limits at $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, then it's wrong (at $-\infty$).

Comment: Well . . . I think we can assume $-\infty$ would have been stated if that was meant . . .

Answer (score 1):

Setting $\dfrac1x=h,x^2+16=\dfrac{1+16h^2}{h^2}\implies\sqrt{x^2+16}=\dfrac{\sqrt{1+16h^2}}{|h|}$

As $h>0,|h|=+h$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+16}+x}{x+3}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{(\sqrt{1+16h^2}+1)h}{h(1+3h)}$$

Cancel out $h$ as $h\ne0$ as $h\to0$

Comment: what do you substitute x for?

Comment: @Kaaagome, Please find the edited version